# Highlight MAX and MIN values in Power BI table visual using DAX

Tags: microsoft-powerbi, dax

I have a table similar to the below in Power BI.

[image]

*DAX to create table:*
`Sample Table = {("A", 2, 3), ("B", 3, 1), ("C", 8, 12), ("D", 4, 15), ("E", , 3), ("F", 6, )}`

**In each column, except the first, I want to highlight the maximum and minimum values.**
So *Value2* would highlight *8* and *2*, *Value3* would highlight *15* and *1*.

I've been scouring the internet trying to find something, but I'm only just learning the language so am like a Monty Python character with a [foreign phrase book](https://www.google.com/search?q=monty+python+hungarian+phrase+book).

I found [this](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/highlighting-the-minimum-and-maximum-values-in-a-power-bi-matrix/) which looks like it's what I'm after, but is based off of different tables and I can't figure out how to get the CurrentValue line.

```
MinMax = 
VAR Vals = 
    CALCULATETABLE(
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            SUMMARIZE ( Sales, 'Product'[Brand], Store[Continent] ),
            "@SalesAmt", [Sales Amount]
        ),
        ALLSELECTED ()
    )
VAR MinValue = MINX ( Vals, [@SalesAmt] )
VAR MaxValue = MAXX ( Vals, [@SalesAmt] )
VAR CurrentValue = [Sales Amount]
VAR Result = 
    SWITCH ( 
        TRUE,
        CurrentValue = MinValue, 1, -- 1 for MIN
        CurrentValue = MaxValue, 2  -- 2 for MAX
    )
RETURN
    Result
```

I tried this, removing the MAXX & MINX versions as I don't think there's an expression to evaluate - I just want the MIN & MAX of that column.  This caused an error though - *a table of multiple values was supplied when a single value was expected*.
I've tried a few variations of this, but nothing seems to be coming close yet.

```
Value2_MinMax = 
    VAR Vals = VALUES('Sample Table'[Value2])
    VAR MaxValue = MAX('Sample Table'[Value2])
    VAR MinValue = MIN('Sample Table'[Value2])
    VAR CurrentValue = Vals
RETURN
    SWITCH (
        TRUE,
        CurrentValue = MinValue, 1,
        CurrentValue = MaxValue, 2
    )
```

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it working, but hoping someone can improve or show a better way.
[image]

The DAX used to create the measure is:

```
MinMax2 = 
VAR Vals = CALCULATETABLE(
                            ADDCOLUMNS('Sample Table', "@Check", [Value3]),
                            ALLSELECTED()
                         )
VAR MinValue = MINX(Vals, [@Check])
VAR MaxValue = MAXX(Vals, [@Check])
VAR CurrentValue = SELECTEDVALUE('Sample Table'[Value3])
VAR Result =
    SWITCH (
        TRUE,
        CurrentValue = MinValue, 1, -- 1 for MIN
        CurrentValue = MaxValue, 2  -- 2 for MAX
    )
RETURN
   Result
```

I then use it in the Conditional Formatting:

[image]

This does mean I need to use a different measure for each column though.
Is it possible to add parameters for the column in question, or is that a new question?